# Is there a name for this "co-dual" vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, terminology

Let $V$ be a $K$-vector space, then the linear transformations $T:K\rightarrow V$ (where $K$ is considered a 1-dimensional vector space over itself) form a vector space
$$ A = \mathrm{span}\{T:K\rightarrow V\} $$
which is isomorphic to $V$.

The dual space is of course $V^* = \mathrm{span}\{T:V\rightarrow K\}$, but is there a name for this "co-dual space" $A$? (I'm using the "co-" here rather loosely.)

Comment: Why do you write "$\mathrm{span}$"? The collection of all linear transformations from one $K$-vector space to another is *already* itself a $K$-vector space. The $\mathrm{span}$ is redundant.

Comment: Yes I know, just wanted to emphasize that it wasn't just a set. But if you think it might cause confusion feel free to edit :)

Comment: It is canonically isomorphic to $V$. The zero operator picks out $0$, and any other operator is just picking out an element of $V$ by where it sends $1$. I'm saying this, because the dual space is not canonically isomorphic (even in finite dimensions), so there is a reason to give a name to it--it's a legitimately new object. But, in our case, we can so naturally identify $A$ with $V$, there is no reason to distinguish between the two.

Comment: @Alex Algebraists and their usual practice of identifying canonically isomorphic objects eh.. :P Fair enough, you should make this an answer.

Comment: @Alex : $\:$ You don't need to special-case the zero operator. $\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Yeah, I didn't in the answer. I don't know why I said that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to give a name to the $K$-space $\text{Hom}_K(K,V)$. It is canonically isomorphic to $V$. Now, while canonical has a technical meaning, here it has a very concrete one. The isomorphism $\text{Hom}_K(K,V)\xrightarrow{\approx}V$ has a trivial, natural, satisfying form:

$$f\mapsto f(1)$$

Think of the elements of $\text{Hom}_K(K,V)$ as just "picking out" an element of $V$. Indeed, an element $f\in\text{Hom}_K(K,V)$ is completely determined by where it sends $1$, and it can send $1$ wherever it wants. Thus, it almost makes sense to think of $\text{Hom}_K(K,V)$ as the following set

$$\text{Hom}_K(K,V)=\left\{\{\text{I pick }v\}:v\in V\right\}$$

When thought about this way, what is the $K$-space operation on $\text{Hom}_K(K,V)$? Well, since $(\alpha f+\beta g)(1)=\alpha f(1)+\beta g(1)$ it's merely

$$\alpha\{\text{I pick }v\}+\beta\{\text{I pick }w\}=\{\text{I pick }\alpha v+\beta w\}$$

If you ignore the superfluous "I pick"s then, this vector space is, as naturally as you'd like $V$.

To pound it in, just a little bit more, think about how silly it would be to name the set of all set maps $\{\text{pt}\}\to X$, for some set $X$. This is JUST $X$.

Comment: Actually, your first line gave me the answer I was looking for in the first place. $\mathrm{Hom}_K(K,V)$ does very nicely. I forgot about that notation. And I still don't necessarily think that naming the set of all maps from a point to some set $X$ is a silly idea... but that's just one preference over another.